# Virtual Environment installation Error

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

When I try to install a virtual environment in my local system I'm getting this error. Could you please help me out to fix this issue?

```
$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /home/sysadmin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

$ sudo pip install virutalenv
sudo: unable to resolve host sysadmin-Veriton-M200-H61
The directory '/home/sysadmin/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/sysadmin/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting virutalenv
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virutalenv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virutalenv
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo there. It's `virtualenv`, not `virutalenv`.

Also, since you already have `pip` installed in `.local`, please don't install `virtualenv` using `sudo`.

Just

```
$ pip install --user virtualenv
```

should do, and `virtualenv` will be available in your user directory (`~/.local/bin` if memory serves, but `find ~ -type f -name virtualenv` will find it for you).